# How can I convert the this cascading dropdown class component to functional one using React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-hooks, cascadingdropdown

I have this cascading dropdown in class component form and it is working fine but I want to convert it to functional one with React Hooks. It is a Country, State, City dropdown. When a user select country, the states under it will load. When they select a state, the cities under it will load. I have changed the constructor part to start using state as seen below. Also, the componentDidMount has been converted to useEffect. The handlers have also been converted.

But the render part below where the form is displayed is giving me tough time. When I tried, I was getting the error that it is not properly arranged. How can I convert the part inside the container div from using `this.` to be in sync with the rest of the function. I know I'll have to do away with `this.` but I don't know how to go about it? The sample function is posted below.

```
function LocationDropdown() {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
            countries : [],
            states : [],
            lgas : [],
            selectedCountry : '--Choose Country--',
            selectedState : '--Choose State--'
        });

    useEffect(() => {
  setState(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            countries : [
                { name: 'Nigeria', value: 'nigeria', 
                states: [ {name: 'Abia', value: 'abia', 
                lgas: [
                        {name: "Aba", value: 'aba'},
                        {name: "Oru", value: 'oru'},

        ]}, {name: 'Adamawa', value: 'adamawa', 
                lgas: [
                        {name: 'Demsa', value: 'demsa'},
                        {name: 'Fufure', value: 'fufure'},
        ]}, 
    },  
            ]
   }));
}, [])

    changeCountry(event) {
        this.setState({selectedCountry: event.target.value});
        this.setState({states : this.state.countries.find(cntry => cntry.name === event.target.value).states});
    }

    changeState(event) {
        this.setState({selectedState: event.target.value});
        const stats = this.state.countries.find(cntry => cntry.name === this.state.selectedCountry).states;
        this.setState({lgas : stats.find(stats => stats.name === event.target.value).lgas});
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div id="container">
                <h2>Cascading or Dependent Dropdown using React</h2>
                <div>
                    <Label>Country</Label>
                    <Select placeholder="Country" value={this.state.selectedCountry} onChange={this.changeCountry}>
                        <option>--Choose Country--</option>
                        {this.state.countries.map((e, key) => {
                            return <option key={key}>{e.name}</option>;
                        })}
                    </Select>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <Label>State</Label>
                    <Select placeholder="State" value={this.state.selectedState} onChange={this.changeState}>
                        <option>--Choose State--</option>
                        {this.state.states.map((e, key) => {
                            return <option key={key}>{e.name}</option>;
                        })}
                    </Select>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <Label>LGA</Label>
                    <Select placeholder="LGA" value={this.state.selectedLga}>
                        <option>--Choose LGA--</option>
                        {this.state.lgas.map((e, key) => {
                            return <option key={key}>{e.name}</option>;
                        })}
                    </Select>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default LocationDropdown;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code. I renamed `state` and `setState`, so it's not confusing with actual States. Also I changed `Select` and `Label` to normal html element so i can test.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function LocationDropdown() {
  const [myData, setMyData] = useState({
    countries: [],
    states: [],
    lgas: [],
    selectedCountry: "--Choose Country--",
    selectedState: "--Choose State--"
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setMyData(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      countries: [
        {
          name: "Nigeria",
          value: "nigeria",
          states: [
            {
              name: "Abia",
              value: "abia",
              lgas: [
                { name: "Aba", value: "aba" },
                { name: "Oru", value: "oru" }
              ]
            },
            {
              name: "Adamawa",
              value: "adamawa",
              lgas: [
                { name: "Demsa", value: "demsa" },
                { name: "Fufure", value: "fufure" }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }));
  }, []);

  const mergeAndUpdateMyData = newData => {
    setMyData({ ...myData, ...newData });
  };

  const changeCountry = event => {
    mergeAndUpdateMyData({
      selectedCountry: event.target.value,
      states: myData.countries.find(cntry => cntry.name === event.target.value)
        .states
    });
  };

  const changeState = event => {
    const stats = myData.countries.find(
      cntry => cntry.name === myData.selectedCountry
    ).states;
    mergeAndUpdateMyData({
      selectedState: event.target.value,
      lgas: stats.find(stats => stats.name === event.target.value).lgas
    });
  };

  return (
    <div id="container">
      <h2>Cascading or Dependent Dropdown using React</h2>
      <div>
        <label>Country</label>
        <select
          placeholder="Country"
          value={myData.selectedCountry}
          onChange={changeCountry}
        >
          <option>--Choose Country--</option>
          {myData.countries.map((country, key) => {
            return (
              <option value={country.name} key={key}>
                {country.name}
              </option>
            );
          })}
        </select>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label>State</label>
        <select
          placeholder="State"
          value={myData.selectedState}
          onChange={changeState}
        >
          <option>--Choose State--</option>
          {myData.states.map((state, key) => {
            return (
              <option value={state.name} key={key}>
                {state.name}
              </option>
            );
          })}
        </select>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label>LGA</label>
        <select placeholder="LGA" value={myData.selectedLga}>
          <option>--Choose LGA--</option>
          {myData.lgas.map((lga, key) => {
            return (
              <option value={lga.name} key={key}>
                {lga.name}
              </option>
            );
          })}
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default LocationDropdown;
```

**EDITED**: Please note that in React, when you set a state, the statement is async. This means when you call setMyData, the value of myData is not updated immediately. So you cannot call mergeAndUpdateMyData multiple times in a row.

By the way, you can use multiple `useState` in one function components. For example:

```
const [countries, setCountries] = useState();
const [lgas, setLags] = useState();
...
```

Comment: I get the error ```TypeError: Object(...) is not a function``` on the line ```setState(prevState => ({``` under the useEffect

Comment: do I need to import setState with React? I also get the error that setState is not defined. I only imported useState

Comment: Hi, I forgot to rename that function. I updated my answer above. The built in `setState` is for class based component.

Comment: Thanks bro. I got ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'states' of undefined``` in the line ```const stats = myData.countries.find(cntry => cntry.name === myData.selectedCountry).states;```

Comment: when I select country the States get populated but when I select any of the States the Lga records don't come up. It's like the state is not changing.

Comment: try add `value` property to option element.  `<option value={e.name} key={key}>{e.name}</option>`  To debug, you can console.log the data passed in the handler functions.

Comment: When I pass the value as suggested and select Country, the value will disappear after selection. The Lgas will also not load

Comment: @Medico I edited the my answer. Or you can try here: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-bhaskara-grqxu?file=/src/LocationDropdown.js

Comment: Thanks bro. That is exactly the result I'm expecting

Comment: Sorry I forgot. By the way, is it possible to have the data in a separate file and import it before using it under useEffect? If possible how do I go about it?

Comment: No problem, i refactored your code to show how to have the data in a separate file. If countries data is static, you don't have to save it to  component state. Please use the same sandbox url above to check.

Comment: Are you referring to this link ```https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-bhaskara-grqxu``` Because it's still the same. I mean something like having a data.js file to store the record. All records country, state and Lga are static

Comment: sorry, try this link:  https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-thunder-mpxp4?file=/src/LocationDropdown.js

Comment: Thank you @Yupeng Like. I really appreciate your input. More power to your elbow 